# Yum can´t update virtual box in centos

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

Linux: centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64

VirtualBox: VirtualBox-6.0.x86_64

If I run this command:
sudo yum list VirtualBox*

This is the output:

```
Installed Packages
VirtualBox-6.0.x86_64                                     6.0.24_139119_el7-1                                      @virtualbox
Available Packages
VirtualBox-4.3.x86_64                                     4.3.40_110317_el7-1                                      virtualbox 
VirtualBox-5.0.x86_64                                     5.0.40_115130_el7-1                                      virtualbox 
VirtualBox-5.1.x86_64                                     5.1.38_122592_el7-1                                      virtualbox 
VirtualBox-5.2.x86_64                                     5.2.44_139111_el7-1                                      virtualbox 
VirtualBox-6.1.x86_64                                     6.1.18_142142_el7-1                                      virtualbox 
[admin@backupserver respaldo]$
```

I want to update VirtualBox to version 6.1, but
if I run this command:

sudo yum update VirtualBox*

this is the output:

```
No packages marked for update
```

I have tried this:

sudo yum clean all

sudo yum update

with no success

Why I can't update VirtualBox using yum?

Answer (score 3):

There's no `VirtualBox-6.0` (`6.0` - is part of its name, **not** version) package available in the repository, so you cannot run `dnf upgrade`.

You'll need to

```bsh
rpm -e VirtualBox-6.0
dnf install VirtualBox-6.1
```

`dnf remove VirtualBox-6.0` will also work but for single packages I prefer to use `rpm` directly as it's a lot faster.

Comment: My version of linux doent have dnf it has yum

Comment: Replace "dnf" above with "yum". For the most part they have the exact same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I follow to update virtual box:

1. Poweroff all virtual machines and close Virtual Box
2. Kill all virtual box related processes. I found them with this command:

```
ps aux | grep virtual
```

and I killed them with:

```
kill -9
```

3. Remove virtual box and reboot:

```
sudo yum remove VirtualBox-6.0.x86_64
sudo reboot
```

4. Install all centos updates and reboot server:

```
sudo yum update
sudo reboot
```

5. Install new virtual box and reboot:

```
sudo yum install VirtualBox-6.1.x86_64
sudo reboot
```